# Why Can't I Comment? Recently Awarded The "Comment Everywhere" Privilege

Tags: support

For some reason I cannot see the "Comment" links on questions or comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comment everywhere](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) requires 50 points. You have 44. You *had* 50, but after some downvotes your rep dropped below that point.

Comment: Ahhh...thanks, toscho.